# Ubuntu 22.04 PHP 8,2 posix_* functions are missing

Tags: 22.04, php

It seems all posix_* functions as described in [this document](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.posix.php) are missing from my installation of php8.2.  At least all the ones I've tried (posix_getppid() posix_getpid(), posix_isatty() and some others.)  I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197366/how-to-install-posix-in-php), which is the same problem exactly, but not on Ubuntu, and for that instance, installation of another package solved the problem.  However, the package that solved that problem, does not seem to be a part of Ubuntu 22.04's packaging.

I have another Ubuntu 22.04 server with PHP8.1 and those posix functions are available there.

The list of all installed packages on the problem system follows.  As far as PHP is concerned, this is a nearly exact mirror of the 8.1 packages installed on the working system. (Working system lacks php8.1-dev and php8.1-intl).

```
alien
apache2
apache2-bin
apache2-data
apache2-utils
apport
at
autoconf
automake
avahi-daemon
bc
bcache-tools
bind9-dnsutils
btrfs-progs
byobu
cifs-utils
cloud-guest-utils
cloud-initramfs-copymods
cloud-initramfs-dyn-netconf
curl
dirmngr
ethtool
fdisk
fonts-ubuntu-console
fortune-mod
ftp
fwupd
gcc
gdebi-core
git
gnupg
google-chrome-stable
htop
info
inotify-tools
iputils-ping
jq
ksh
landscape-common
libaio1
libapache2-mod-php8.2
libapr1
libaprutil1
libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3
libaprutil1-ldap
libasn1-8-heimdal
libbrotli1
libbsd-dev
libcgi-fast-perl
libcgi-pm-perl
libcurl4
libcurl4-openssl-dev
libdiscid-dev
libdvd-pkg
libdvdcss-dev
libdvdcss2
libencode-locale-perl
libevent-core-2.1-7
libfcgi-perl
libfdisk1
libgdbm-compat4
libgl1-mesa-dev
libgssapi3-heimdal
libhcrypto4-heimdal
libheimbase1-heimdal
libheimntlm0-heimdal
libhtml-parser-perl
libhtml-tagset-perl
libhtml-template-perl
libhttp-date-perl
libhttp-message-perl
libhx509-5-heimdal
libio-html-perl
libjansson4
libjpeg-dev
libkrb5-26-heimdal
libldap-2.4-2
libldap-common
liblua5.2-0
liblwp-mediatypes-perl
libmecab2
libncurses5
libncurses6
libnghttp2-14
libnl-3-200
libnl-route-3-200
libperl5.30
libpng-dev
libroken18-heimdal
librtmp1
libsasl2-2
libsasl2-modules
libsasl2-modules-db
libsodium23
libssh-4
libssl-dev
libtimedate-perl
liburi-perl
libwebp-dev
libwind0-heimdal
libxkbcommon-x11-0
libzip-dev
lsdvd
lvm2
lxd-agent-loader
makemkv-bin
makemkv-oss
mdadm
mecab-ipadic
mecab-ipadic-utf8
mecab-utils
mediainfo
megacli
molly-guard
motd-news-config
mpt-status
multipath-tools
mysql-client
mysql-client-8.0
mysql-client-core-8.0
mysql-common
mysql-server
mysql-server-8.0
mysql-server-core-8.0
ncurses-base
open-iscsi
open-vm-tools
openvpn
overlayroot
patch
perl
perl-modules-5.30
php-common
php-curl
php-db
php-dev
php-gd
php-intl
php-json
php-ldap
php-mbstring
php-mysql
php-pear
php-phpdbg
php-ssh2
php-xml
php-zip
php8.2-cli
php8.2-common
php8.2-curl
php8.2-dev
php8.2-gd
php8.2-intl
php8.2-ldap
php8.2-mbstring
php8.2-mysql
php8.2-opcache
php8.2-pgsql
php8.2-phpdbg
php8.2-readline
php8.2-ssh2
php8.2-xdebug
php8.2-xml
php8.2-zip
pkg-php-tools
plexmediaserver
pollinate
ppa-purge
python3-nacl
python3-pip
python3-pymacaroons
regionset
rsync
sabnzbdplus
samba
screen
smartmontools
software-properties-common
sosreport
ssl-cert
sudo
tcpdump
telnet
time
tmux
transmission-cli
transmission-common
transmission-daemon
ubuntu-drivers-common
ubuntu-standard
unzip
update-manager-core
update-notifier-common
vim
vlc
wget
x11-apps
xfsprogs
zip
```

I've not seen this sort of problem before... can someone help me identify what might be missing, or steps I might try to solve the problem?  (I did uninstall and reinstall all PHP packages on the problem system.  No warnings, no errors, no improvement.)

Thanks.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 has no php8.2 packages, not even in backports, or am I wrong?

Comment: Marco is correct. Ubuntu 22.04 [uses PHP 8.1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=jammy&keywords=php). The same is said for Ubuntu 23.04. You may want to check with the source of your 8.2 packages, be it from Ondrej or elsewhere 

Comment: Oh, well that would explain it!  I don't know where I got the idea to us 8.2.  I'll re-do it.  Thanks much for the tip. @Marco  I'll update here with success/fail, and you can turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: Thanks @Marco - feel free to make your comment an answer; I will accept it.  Problem has been overcome by removal of 8.2 and installation of 8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 22.04 has no php8.2 packages, better use the official Ubunutu packages which are php8.1

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Marco.  I don't know what led me down the 8.2 path... what I do is not so cutting edge.  I removed all php8.2* stuff and installed php8.1 in iits place... now all is good.  I appreciate the help.